# What is the right UI for showing total in graph

Tags: web

Any UI Alternatives for showing total in graph which is distributed in two different categories.

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be in graph view?

Answer (score 1):

Try a graph like this.
Here you can show the context of whole data set
and here it feels visually attractive and it is easy to understand and compare
[image]

Let me know if i can help you more

Comment: Not looking for a graph view. any other concepts?

Comment: yes please mention in question about what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Usually, graphs tend to have textual descriptions/data attached to them where details like Total can be shown.

However, one of the standard ways of showing the height of the bar is to place it on top of the individual bars like so:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEOc8Q.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Not looking for a graph view. any other concepts?

Comment: Then could you change your question accordingly because your question specifically says graph

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to think also of the **stacked horizontal bar**, as it is presented in the right image.

[image: horizontal]

Specifically for  your case:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftqsal.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>